# How can i open a form with Safari in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari

I have a form string like "<form>...</form>", and I want to open it with Safari using Objective C code, Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply insert this string under HTML body tags and create a .html file.

Read HTML files and load in web view:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@“sample” ofType:@“html” inDirectory:nil];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```